# Split binary data into chunks and append the Oracle LONG RAW column value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle10g, entity

Our legacy Oracle application stores all PDF documents in binary data format using the LONG RAW data type. Now we need to insert or update the legacy table from the new front-end using Entity framework 6.4. Since the file size is very large, we get the error when updating records into the LONG RAW datatype. Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the existing datatype to BLOB as it will break the legacy system. I am assuming we can append the LONG RAW column value by splitting the data into chunks in Oracle Stored procedure. Is there any sample code anyone can provide to insert large binary data into LONG RAW as chunks?

We also tried with a stored procedure, but we get the same type of error. See the sample code below.

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\document.pdf");          
   StoredProcedureParameter[] params = new StoredProcedureParameter[2];
   params[0] = new StoredProcedureParameter { Name = "DATA_TYPE", Value = '.pdf', InputType = OracleDbType.Varchar2 };
   params[1] = new StoredProcedureParameter { Name = "LONG_RAW_DATA", Value = bytes, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.InputOutput,InputType = OracleDbType.LongRaw };
   var dbSearch = _repository.ExecuteStoredProcedure("ADD_DOCUMENT", params);
```

Instead of passing LongRow inputType, I guess I should pass CLOB data and insert it as chunks within Oracle. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have more or less answered your own question here, in that, you've hit a stack of limitations of LONG RAW that BLOB was built to resolve. When it comes to dealing with LONG RAQ, you're pretty much into C or Java territory. There's very little PL/SQL facilities available here

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald - According to Oracle document, LONG RAW DATATYPE can store 2^31-1 bytes but we cannot save more than 3999 bytes. Is there anyway we can store 30MB documents stored in the LONG RAW column?

Comment: Yes ... but you have to use C or Java to do so